# JavaScript: resolve next event as a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, promise, mocha.js

For the purpose of testing, I want somehow to wrap events into promises(it's easier to wait for a promise resolution in mocha). So, I write something like:

```
const collectEvents = (eventEmmiter, eventName, count=1) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const result = []
    const listener = (msg) => {
      result.push(msg)
      if(result.length === count) {
        resolve(result)
        eventEmmiter.removeListener(eventName, listener)
      }
    }
    eventEmmiter.on(eventName, listener)
  })
}
```

and use it like this:

```
Promise.all([
  collectEvents(client1, 'message'),
  collectEvents(client2, 'message')
]).then(
```

it works, but I feel like I invented the wheel again. Did I? is there a standard way to achieve the behavior?

Comment: I would add an `eventEmitter.on("error", reject)` (and the respective `removeListener`) but apart from that it looks totally fine. No, the standard library doesn't provide such a utility yet afaik.

Comment: in this particular case, a client provides an "error" event; But there is no specification about the "error" event in general.

Comment: True, although *all* standard streams I've seen so far provide an error event. Sure, it's not codified, and that's why there is no standard promisification utility either - everyone needs it to behave a little differently. Consider also the case that the stream ends before emitting `count` events - would you want to reject then?

Comment: >would you want to reject then?
it's also a kinda question which I don't want to answer:) I use the function for testing. So, I rely on mocha timeouts in the case